# Looking for quantitative studies on languages' degree of synthesis

Tags: linguistic-typology

Languages lie on an analytic-synthetic spectrum, where more analytic languages use free/unbounded grammatical morphemes while synthetic languages use bounded grammatical morphemes. Unbounded grammatical morphemes in my area of research (NLP) is also generally known as function words.

I have been looking for quantitative studies of a large number of languages' distribution of unbounded grammatical morphemes for the purpose of placing them somewhere on this spectrum. The wikipedia article on Synthetic language talks about their "degrees of synthesis".

I'm imagining the reasoning to go something like, "in language X we classify a set of words as function words, which take up N% of the total amount of tokens in our corpus. Since that is a smaller percentage than language Y, we consider Y to be a more analytic language than X."

Unfortunately I haven't had any luck finding such a study. Is there a reason for this, or am I just using the wrong keywords in my search?

Comment: You could start with [WALS on inflectional synthesis of verbs](http://wals.info/chapter/22).